# Children's Book of short stories about dragons

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, dragons

I am desperate to find a book I owned around 2005. It was a collection of short stories about dragons, and I'm sure that some of them had been published elsewhere and were by well-known authors. I believe, though I am not sure, that it included an excerpt from *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*. There may also have been a piece by E. Nesbitt. There might have been an excerpt from *The Hobbit* but I'm not certain.

I do know that there was a story about a dragon that someone found in their basement, maybe? I believe the setting was small-town old-timey Europe, with some anachronistic elements. The protagonist captures the dragon and feeds it milk until it turns into a cat.

There may also have been a story about St. George.

I do know that the book was illustrated. I believe there were a few full-color pages interspersed with black & white or linework. The artwork often felt haphazard or rough to me- similar to Charles Vess's work, I think. It was a hardcover book, not especially thick, but almost square, about the same across (closed) as it was tall. The book was in English and I am located in the US. I feel like it had a super generic name, like "The Dragon Book," or something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great job including enough information to find the book! Using [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org), I believe I've found it: *The Book of Dragons*, edited by Michael Hague. It includes "The Adventures of Eustace" by C.S. Lewis and "The Dragon Tamers" by E. Nesbit. There was also an excerpt from *The Hobbit*. It also includes interior artwork by Michael Hague.

The cover art is:

[image: Michael Hague cover for The Book of Dragons]

The full contents can be found on ISFDB [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?285819).

Comment: Wow, that's it!. I had forgotten Michael Hauge illustrated- probably because I've always found his work slightly off-putting.